# What is the general attitude in Samarla towards Daemonism (Ketty Jay series)

Tags: steampunk, tales-of-the-ketty-jay

I know that in the third Ketty Jay novel, the Iron Jackal, the majority of the book takes place in Samarla. However, it's been a long time since I've read the book and I have misplaced my copy. My question is, what was the general stance towards Daemonism in Samarla?

Comment: General stance by *whom*? A quick scan through suggests that daemonists are killed/hung in some parts.

Comment: "*There were plenty, like the Awakeners and their followers, who thought daemonists should be hanged for dabbling with strange and terrible entities.*" - Ketty Jay #02

Comment: "*It was the Awakeners that championed the persecution of daemonists. Many good men and women had been hanged because of them.*"  - Ketty Jay #02

Comment: "*But a century of this superstitious twaddle has made daemonists the most vilified people on the planet. Most people would rather associate with a Samarlan than a daemonist.”*" - Ketty Jay #01